# How to display data in Grid view based on logged In user.?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am creating courier company application base on C# desktop application with SQL server. For that purpose I would like to create client user panel.

What I want to display all shipments booked by user in data grid view. But currently when I do so. It will display all the data store in particular table of database. Whereas I want to show only data which is booked by the user who is logged in at current time.

Looking forward for priority response in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Create a procedure or a view that Selects only the data that you want to be displayed in the grid.  Bind the Data Grid View to that view/procedure.

Procedures (this way you can write the procedure to return only the shipments belonging to the user you pass into the @User parameter):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql

Views:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql

Data Grids and DataBinding:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings(v=vs.110).aspx

EDIT:  I obviously have no idea what your structure looks like, but taking this code and modifying it a bit should get you started.  Once you have the Select statement you want, just wrap the whole thing in a stored procedure.

```
--@UserID will become your Input Parameter
DECLARE @UserID INT = 115;

--Use @UserID to ensure only shipments for that UserID come back
SELECT [ShipmentID], [ShipmentDestination], [OrderID]
FROM [dbo].[Shipments]
WHERE [AssignedTo] = @UserID;
```

LINQ (in case you haven't already set up connections to your DB): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx

Comment: Thanks for details. Could you pls explain a litter bit what exactly would be store procedure for that.

Comment: @saddambhatti  Edited my response.  Should get you on your way.